# The right word or phrase of an act of telling false bad stories about someone deliberately?

Tags: phrases, pejorative-language

My subordinate at the workplace has a problem of not accepting reprimand when she has done wrong.  She always becomes shaking with anger threatening to leave her job and then spreads the false stories about how she is being handled at the workplace by her supervisor, me.  So I would like to have the relevant word of her act of **spreading false accusations about me** in my report to our employer for protection.

Comment: A [Reverse dictionary search](http://www.onelook.com/?w=*&loc=revfp2&clue=spreading+false+accusations) yields ***calumny*** for which [a huge number of alternatives](http://thesaurus.com/browse/calumny) can be found.

Comment: I should have closed this earlier. ***Any one*** of the huge number of alternatives will work. If you would like to edit your question to ask about specific alternatives (and [show your research](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed)) then it can be re-opened.

Comment: The expression 'spreading false accusations about me' seems totally  appropriate. Is this a rant or a misdirected appeal for moral support?

Answer (score 3):

According to Dictionary.com, *[Slander](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/slander)* is a good word for what you describe.

> *slander*, noun: *a malicious, false, and defamatory statement or report: *a slander against his good name.**
>
> *slander*, verb: ***1** ***with*** object :to utter slander against; defame.*
>   **2.** ***without*** object: to utter or circulate slander.